# How to correctly insert a table when asking questions

Tags: support

When posting a question on Stack Overflow where I am inserting a table it keeps coming out in the following format:

### ID|Date

1|20111020
2|20111020
3|20111020
4|20111020
5|20111020

How can I do this correctly so someone doesn't have to keep editing my posts? I have looked at the advanced help but can't see the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your table in `<pre> ... </pre>` tags.

```
ID|Date
---------
1|20111020
2|20111020
3|20111020
4|20111020
5|20111020
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the content that you want to format and click the `{}` icon.